# Generate a Get query string in Java

Tags: java

I want to generate a Get query string in java like so

```
www.example.com/somethingToGet?key1=value&key2=value....
```

So my method has 2 parameters the base url(www.example.com/somethingToGet) is the first argument and the 2nd argument is a map data structure. I want to iterate over the map and generate a string like so

```
key1=value&key2=value....
```

It shouldn't end with ampersand.
I don't want to use any built in functions, I want to know the logic how such strings are generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
public static String getQuery(String base, java.util.Map<String, String> map) {
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(base);
    str.append('?');
    boolean first = true;
    for (java.util.Map.Entry<String, String> e : map.entrySet()) {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            str.append('&');
        str.append(e.getKey());
        str.append('=');
        str.append(e.getValue());
    }
    return str.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [format method in URLEncoder](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html#format%28java.lang.Iterable,%20char,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) class from the Apache HttpComponents library to create a query string. As per the documentation it

```
Returns a String that is suitable for use as an application/x-www-form-urlencoded list of parameters in an HTTP PUT or HTTP POST.
```